# Reading from random access file in Java

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I am trying to set up a while loop that will read from a RandomAccessFile and stop when it reaches the end of the file. But every time I try running the program I get an error.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
    final int EOF = -1;

    while(raf.readInt() != EOF){

    id = raf.readInt();
    existingMileage = raf.readInt();
    gasCost = raf.readInt();
    ndays = raf.readInt();
    rate = raf.readInt();
    totalCharge = raf.readInt();
    discount = raf.readInt();
    tax = raf.readInt();
    netCharge = raf.readInt();
    returnMileage = raf.readInt();

    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(Unknown Source)
at TakeHome.TakeHome.fileReaderMethod(TakeHome.java:127)
at TakeHome.TakeHome.main(TakeHome.java:20)
```

Comment: Are you sure your `filename` is the correct filepath?

Comment: That looks like your file is terminated before it has that amount of int to read

Answer (score 4):

```
 final int EOF = -1;
```

You made that up. It isn't in the Javadoc. The `readInt()` method doesn't return -1 at end of file. It can't. -1 is an in-band value. It throws the very `EOFException` you are getting.

You're also throwing the `int` that you read at the EOF test away, so you're reaching end of file sooner than you should be.

You should loop `while (true)`, catch `EOFException`, and break when you catch it.

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean? What argument should I be using?

Comment: What part of 'loop `while (true)` ...' etc don't you understand? And what argument are you talking about?

Comment: You can't have read one single word of my answer. Otherwise you would know (a) that `(readInt() == -1)` is incorrect as a test for EOS, and (b) that I have already told you what to loop on and how to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to handle a RandomAccessFile:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("testFile", "r");

//random code in between

while(true){
   try{
      //do stuff with code, like reading from file
   } catch(EOFException e){
      break;
   }
}

//do some more stuff if you like

file.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

The file you are reading needs to be also created as a binary file.
If you are trying to read from a file that you created as text then the reader will read 4 bytes for the  int and for example if you have a sequence of numbers 12345678 the reader doesn't know that these are separate numbers and will treat it as one integer and then go to the end of file.
Another thing to mention is that you need to catch the `EOFException` to end the loop cause -1 can also be an integer.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** Try this

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File("/path/to/file"), "rw");
        int numberCounter = 0;
        int totalNumbers = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumbers; i++)
        {
            raf.writeInt(i * 2);
        }

        raf.seek(0);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int id = raf.readInt();
                System.out.println(id);
                numberCounter++;

            }
        }
        catch (EOFException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Total number " + numberCounter);
            System.out.println("End of file reached!");
        }
        finally
        {
            raf.close();
        }
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
Total number 10
End of file reached!
```

Comment: There's no evidence that he isn't using a binary file.

Comment: There's no need to guess. You identified one problem correctly. No need to devote the other 95% of your answer to a mere speculation.